# Bubble sort an Array of pointers of another arrays in a function (C)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I want to make a bubble sort function of an array of pointers that each of the pointers point to another arrays - inside of function and i'm getting a error that i violated a writing location (Visual Studio)

P.S, I do `(*parr)++` because the first value of each array shows the length of the array without the first value so i need to start bubble sorting from the second box (`arr[1]` and not `arr[0]` for example ).
can someone write to me how can i fix it?
Thanks for help
(I need to sort the values of the original arrays not the pointer of the arrays).

```
int main(void){

    int i = 0;
    int arr0[4] = { 3, 9, 6, 7 };
    int arr1[3] = { 2, 5, 5 };
    int arr2[1] = { 0 };
    int arr3[2] = { 1, 6 };
    int arr4[5] = { 4, 5, 6, 2, 1 };
    int* parr[5] = { arr0, arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 };
    func1(parr);


    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
void func1(int** parr)
{
    int i;
    int temp;
    int j;
    int k;
    int length;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++, (parr)++)
    {
        length = **parr;
        (*parr)++;
        for (j = 0; j < length-1; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < length - j - 1; k++, (*parr)++)
            {
                if ((**parr)>(*(*parr + 1)))
                {
                    temp = **(parr);
                    **(parr) = (*(*parr + 1));
                    (*(*parr + 1)) = temp;
                }
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: So.. you have five `int` array, and you're trying to bubble sort *each* array? Or you have five `int` array and you're trying to bubble sort them *all* as-if one consecutive array? Update *the question* with the answer please. And I don't think `(*parr)++` is doing what you think, but I may be misunderstanding your question. And *all* of this is assuming you actually setup the pointer array correctly; something your question shows no evidence of whatsoever.

Comment: Seems you must use another pointer variable to sort the target arrays. parr points to the array that has the pointers to the other arrays. Take one element of parr, sort that array (using the other pointer var), now take the next entry of parr, sort that array (using the other pointer var), etc.

Comment: That's what I mean, I don't know if all of you understood:

parr[5] = {arr0,arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4}
arr0[5] = ????
and so on.

I will try the fixes you guys offered

Comment: please post a complete example - add the calling code.

Comment: Sorry for double posting but @WhozCraig do you think it's something in the main function that I haven't done correct?

Comment: If you try the inner for-loop on just one array, with one pointer, does it work then?

Comment: @Joel no, your main looks correct (and thanks for posting it). I would also pass the sequence length (the number of pointers), but that doesn't appear to be related to your core problem. Ultimately this will be much easier to wrangle if you write a *basic* bubble sort function (takes an `int ar[]` and a `len`), then invoke *that* from your "sort these arrays" function. And I think there are places in this where you should be using `+1`, not `++`.

Comment: @Krycke I've tested it and it seems to work, I think it's something in the outer loop maybe?

Comment: I can't see any wrong doings in the outer loop either. I would do as @Joel suggests, break it up into different functions and try them out one at a time to see where the mistake is, or use some kind of debugger where you can step though your code.

Comment: [Something like this](http://ideone.com/9VgUDz). (referring to my prior comment). The thing that is unclear to me (besides the stuff mentioned earlier) is whether you want the pointer array to contain pointers that no longer reference the length-element (lead element) in each sub-array (which `(*parr)++` would seem to suggest you don't). I don't see why it should matter, as that length is still in the original arrays anyway. It is none-the-less not clear if that is a desire.

Comment: @WhozCraig what i'm trying to do is this:
arr0[4] = {3,?,?,?};
The number 3 shows how many values will be after and my task here is to do a bubble sort of those elements ( not including the value 3)
for example:
arr0[4] = {3,5,1,2}
After the sorting:
arr0 = {3,2,1,5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. It is easier in func1 to use dereferenceing as parr[i][k] rather than moving the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func1(int** parr);

int main(void){
    int j;
    int arr0[4] = { 3, 9, 6, 7 };
    int arr1[3] = { 2, 5, 5 };
    int arr2[1] = { 0 };
    int arr3[2] = { 1, 6 };
    int arr4[5] = { 4, 5, 6, 2, 1 };
    int* parr[5] = { arr0, arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 };
    func1(parr);
    for (j = 1; j <= arr0[0]; j++)
    {
        printf ( "arr0[%d] %d\n", j, arr0[j]);
    }
    for (j = 1; j <= arr4[0]; j++)
    {
        printf ( "arr4[%d] %d\n", j, arr4[j]);
    }
    return (0);
}

void func1(int** parr)
{
    int i;
    int temp;
    int j;
    int k;
    int length;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        length = **parr;

        for (j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            for (k = 1; k < length - j; k++)
            {
                temp = *((*parr)+k);
                if (*((*parr)+k)>*((*parr)+k+1))
                {
                    temp = *((*parr)+k);
                    *((*parr)+k) = *((*parr)+k+1);
                    *((*parr)+k+1) = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        *parr++;// next array
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Like you said, it seems to work so I'll just compare it to my original code and try to see what have I done wrong,
thank you once again!